# pybind11 + cmake project. Avoid full recompile when calling pip install

Tags: cmake, pybind11

I'm working on a C++ Pybind11 project with CMake and I'm following this example to setup mu build system:

https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example

Now, when I run

```
pip install <project>
```

everything works perfectly, but the problem is that this triggers a full rebuild everytime. Since the project is quite large, I'm looking for a way to avoid recompilation of pieces of code that haven't changed. I search around but without much success. I tried to add

```
 f"-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache"
```

in the CMake args, and tried calling `pip install -e`, but it always rebuilds everything from scratch. Does anyone know what is the best practice in this case?